# Returning a correct descendant type from a list of base type

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance

I have a base class Foo with a property for identify the primary key from a data base item.
Other classes descend from my base class Foo and contains another properties for particularities these classes. Each descended class represents a distinct table in the database.

Generally when these data are loaded these items are stored in the same list of type List<Foo>.

And when I need to use some item I find this based on the primary key.

My problem occurs when these items have the same primary key, and when look a item from a descended class FooB eventually find a class FooA because this is comes first, then the places that perform a cast to FooB raise a excpetion.

```
var list = new List<Foo>();

list.Add(new FooA() { PrimaryKey = 1 });
list.Add(nwe FooB() { PrimaryKey = 1 });

public Foo FindItem(int pk)
{
    return list.First(it => it.PrimaryKey == 1);
}
```

In many places I use this method to find my item according to my needs.

```
var item = (FooB)FindItem(1);
```

In other classes:

```
var item = (FooA)FindItem(1);
```

In my case this code is used in many places in the system, changing the List<Foo> to lists of the  descended item is a solution but this means making changes in many places because I can not pass the type of each item everywhere I use.

I need a solution that does not change the base list.

Comment: why can't you change the base list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to rewrite the `FindItem(1)` method to return not one instance of `Foo` but instead a special object that will contain both `FooA` instance with `PrimaryKey==1` and the `FooB` instance with `PrimaryKey==1`.

The second step is to provide cast operators that will convert this special object to the type you need so that the code `var item = (FooB)FindItem(1)` will work as expected.

Below is fully working code that implements such a solution. The main drawback is that you have to provide the cast operator implementations for each derived type you are using. You might also be able to derive `FooWrapper` from `Foo` (would be very simple in this case with just a single property in `Foo` but it depends on your actual `Foo` class).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FooWrapper
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

        static FooWrapper FindItem(int id)
        {
            return new FooWrapper(list.Where(o => o.PrimaryKey == id));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            list.Add(new FooA() { PrimaryKey = 1, Title = "aaa" });
            list.Add(new FooB() { PrimaryKey = 1, Age = 123 });

            // test the implicit cast to Foo type. this prefers the FooA type.
            Foo item = FindItem(1);
            Console.WriteLine(item.PrimaryKey + " - " + item.GetType().Name);

            // retrieve the FooWrapper and cast it to FooA type.
            var itema = (FooA)FindItem(1);
            Console.WriteLine(itema.PrimaryKey + " - " + itema.Title + " - " + itema.GetType().Name);

            // retrieve the FooWrapper and cast it to FooB type. The wrapper instance 
            // retrieved is the same, but the cast retrieves the correct type
            var itemb = (FooB)FindItem(1);
            Console.WriteLine(itemb.PrimaryKey + " - " + itemb.Age + " - " + itemb.GetType().Name);
        }
    }

    public sealed class FooWrapper
    {
        private FooA _a;
        private FooB _b;

        public FooWrapper(IEnumerable<Foo> items)
        {
            FooA a;
            FooB b;
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                a = i as FooA;
                if (a != null)
                {
                    this._a = a;
                }
                else
                {
                    b = i as FooB;
                    if (b != null)
                        this._b = b;
                }
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator Foo(FooWrapper obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            return obj._a == null ? (Foo)obj._b : obj._a;
        }

        public static explicit operator FooA(FooWrapper obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            return obj._a;
        }

        public static explicit operator FooB(FooWrapper obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            return obj._b;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Foo
    {
        public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooA : Foo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooB : Foo
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, your detailed code makes my second answer (which basically describes the same idea) obsolete (just deleted it). I would remove the implicit Foo operator, though, since the OP mentioned that he stores the result in a variable of type `Foo` and only later casts it to `FooA` or `FooB`.

Comment: the problem with storing it in variable of type `Foo` is that when you derive `FooWrapper` from `Foo`, this code will still fail: `Foo i = FindItem(1); var ia = (FooA)i;` and you will have to write `var ia = (FooA)(FooWrapper)ia;` which is not nice since you now have to know when it is the wrapper and when not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public T FindItem<T>(int pk) where T : Foo
{
    return list.OfType<T>().First(it => it.PrimaryKey == 1);
}
```

Usage:

```
var item = FindItem<FooB>(1);
```

`OfType<T>` has two beneficial effects on `list`:

- It filters the list items to those of type `T` and
- it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so the return value of `FindItem` is already correctly typed and does not need to be cast.

Comment: This solution would solve my problem but in most places I store the result in a base class Foo or a list of base class List<Foo> and then convert to a specific type.

Comment: @Richard: That's OK. Since `FooB` is a subtype of `Foo`, you can store the return value of `FindItem<FooB>` in a variable of type `Foo` (or in a list of type `List<Foo>`).

Comment: Ok, if I use generics it means changing everywhere where method FindItem is used. I can not pass the type of each item everywhere I use

Comment: @Richard: Yes. In that case, Knagis solution is the only alternative I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics in your FindItem function:

```
public T FindItem<T> (int pk) where T : Foo
{
    return list.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault(it => it.PrimaryKey == pk);
}
```